# update internet headers of mail with microsoft graph api

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api, office365-restapi

I am trying to edit internet headers of outlook mails of Office 365 using the graph API. But I find that using `REST` calls to `GET`

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages

I can not even get the internet header details of mails (I am getting other fields like body,subject,etc.).

Also using `REST` call to `PATCH`

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/

I am not able to update internet headers.
Is it possible in any way to update internet headers of mail using the GRAPH APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't possible today.

Comment: Do you have a concrete scenario for needing to see or edit the internet headers on mails?  This might help to prioritize this request.  Also please post an idea here: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis

Comment: Thanks Jason and Dan for the info!

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT We've had messages come in with the same ConversationID when they aren't related - the user has used the same subject but, as far as we can tell, was not replying to another message. This has caused us problems with threading in our system and therefore the In-Reply-To and References headers would make it possible for us to thread correctly.